# Configure a host to be a known one for SSH for all users

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, known-hosts

Context: Modern Ubuntu server.

We have a certain host that should be known to all users on all machines. This is to avoid interactive prompt on first connect to it (which fails in non-interactive mode).

Is there a way to configure this OS-wide, without touching `known-hosts` of users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the key in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`.  You can override this file with the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` with the `GlobalKnownHostsFile` setting.